# virtualbox extensions pack installation failed

Tags: virtualbox

I have been trying to install virtualbox extension pack.
so I downloaded its file from the **http://www.virtualbox.org** and i ran it.
but I encountered the following error:

```
Failed to install the Extension Pack
/home/waezi/www/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.0-118431.vbox-extpack.VBoxExtPackRegister returned VERR_VERSION_MISMATCH, pReg=0000000000000000 ErrInfo='VirtualBox version mismatch - expected 5.2 got 5.1'.
Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: ExtPackManagerWrap Interface: IExtPackManager {edba9d10-45d8-b440-1712-46ac0c9bc4c5}
```

I have to mention that I am connecting from Iran.

anybody can help???!!!!

Comment: The extension pack you have isn't for the Virtualbox version you have installed please check the version specific to your Virtualbox install. What Virtualbox version are you using?

Comment: use can use sudo `apt install virtualbox-ext-pack` to install the extension pack.

Answer (score 2):

The extension pack that you downloaded is for a different, later version of VirtualBox (v5.2) than the one currently installed on the system in question (v5.1). You need to either

- upgrade the VirtualBox installation to v5.2 or
- download and install the extension pack for v5.1.